# Regular expression for including blank & blank or &

Tags: regex

I'am looking for a regular expression to search for : `a&b`
the possibility are :

```
a&b
a & b
A&B
A & B
A&b
a&B
A & b
a & B
```

so far so good i've made :

```
.*[Aa]&[Bb].*
```

but i don't have clue on how to do space or not for the &

like `&` OR `\ & \` (blank & blank)

regards and thanks

Comment: `[Aa]\s*&\s*[Bb]` or `[Aa][[:space:]]*&[[:space:]]*[Bb]` - depends on the regex flavor.

Comment: You can also do \s+ in case there are one or more spaces but it doesn't look like that's happening in your sample set.

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a very simple regex. Just make it case insensitive `i` and the spaces optional `?`, i.e.:

```
/a ?& ?b/i
```

[Demo and Explanation](https://regex101.com/r/vndusE/2)

Answer (score 1):

That ain't so tough. You just need to add optional whitespace `\s`.

**Regex:** `.*[Aa]\s?&\s?[Bb].*`

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SXeF6S/1/)